# Ruby date time in string conversion to date time with milliseconds

Tags: ruby

This is a Ruby question (1.9.1)

I have the following date and time in a string:

```
29 Sep 2013 12:25:00.367
```

I first want to convert it from string to date and time and then
add 10 seconds to it and convert it back to the same string format as
above.

I wrote this code:

```
format = "%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S"
date_time = "29 Sep 2013 22:11:30.195"
parsed_time = DateTime.strptime(date_time, format)
puts " new date time is #{parsed_time}"
```

Which outputs:

```
new date time is 2013-09-29T22:11:30+00:00
```

I did not see "195". I tried `format = "%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S.%3N"` and this gives:

```
fileOpTest:34:in `strptime': invalid date (ArgumentError) from fileOpTest:34:in `<main>'
```

Comment: You should upgrade your Ruby version, v1.9.1 is old and buggy.

Comment: Same problem occurs with ruby 2.1: b = DateTime.current.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%3N"); DateTime.strptime(b, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%6L") produces same error

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This can be done very easily using the [Time class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html).  You can add to a Time by adding seconds. Then use #strftime

```
t= Time.parse('29 Sep 2013 12:25:00.367')
=> 2013-09-29 12:25:00 -0400
t=t + 10
=> 2013-09-29 12:25:10 -0400
t.strftime("%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S.%3N")
=> "29 Sep 2013 12:25:10.367"
```